# Python import statement after class/function definition

Tags: python, class, import, module

I'm trying to import a function from a `python` module. That function is declared on the module I'm calling `import` from, but nevertheless I'm using that function on the other file.

Like so:

**context.py**

```
from elements import *
class Context:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def load():
        print "load code here"
```

elements.py

```
from context import *
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        Context.load() # NameError: global name 'load' is not defined
```

As someone who comes from Java, seems like applying the same nested class accessing logic doesn't work in Python. I'm wondering what could be the best practice here, since it doesn't seem right to put the `import` statement below the `Context` class. I searched about this but the material wasn't clear about this practice.

**Also, at `context.py` I'm using instances of classes defined at `elements`, and vice versa. So my question is really what would be the best importing practice here.**

Another related question: is it good practice to encapsulate functions and variables inside Classes in Python or should I use global functions/variables instead?

Comment: Don't you need to instantiate your `Context` class before applying `load` to it ? EDIT : no, static method

Comment: It's a static method so I suppose not

Comment: oh my bad, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, in Python this is considered a circular import error -- and can be incredibly frustrating.  `elements` is importing from `context` and vice-versa.  This may be possible in Java with magic compiler tricks but since Python is (mostly) interpreted, this isn't possible*.

Another unstated difference between Java and Python is that a Python class is closer to a hashmap with a special API than a proper Java class.  As such, it is perfectly acceptable and preferable to put classes that have a tight interdependence (such as the ones you wrote) in the same Python module.  This will remove the circular import error.

In general, you want to organize *library* modules by dependency level -- meaning, the leaves of your `lib` folder do not import from anything else in your project, and as you progress closer to the root, more imports are drawn upon.  To the best of your ability you want your import structure to be a tree, not a spiderweb (if that makes any sense).  Without a compiler, it's the only way I've found in a large (multi-million line) Python project to maintain sanity.

The above comments are generally considered best practice, this next suggestion is highly opinionated:

I would recommend structuring *executable* modules around I/O boundaries.  It becomes very tempting to build tightly interconnected fabrics of Python objects with complicated inheritance structures passed by reference.  While on a small and medium scale this offers development advantages, on a larger scale you lose the ability to easily integrate concurrency since you've taken away the ability for the code to be transfer-layer agnostic.

**Edit:**  Okay, it IS possible by playing around with import statement ordering, using the `__import__` method, etc., to hack the import framework and accomplish this.  However, you should NOT do this if you intend to have a large project -- it is very brittle and difficult to explain to a team.  It seems like you're more interested in best practices, which is how I directed my answer.  Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: Excelent answer! This is what I was looking for. Very clear and informative.

Comment: No problem!  I know Python can be madness to folks coming from more rigorous languages.  I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

In `context.py` file you should add `def` before `__init__`, also class methods do not take `self`:

```
class Context:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def load():
        print "load code here"
```

then in another file:

```
from context import Context

class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        Context.load()
```

Comment: You're right, mistakes copying the code. But how could I link them effectively considering that in 'context.py' I'm using instances defined at 'elements.py' and vice-versa? What would be a good import practice here?

Comment: Why you would do something like that ?

Comment: I'm using two modules: one is a context of the game (has its game loop, loading images functions, context variables like screen resolution, fps, etc), and the other is its elements (like items, characters, etc). On context I need to create game elements (like characters) in order to run the game loop. On the other hand, within elements I need to call context functions and variables such as the ones I mentioned. This is a very Javaesque approach, but If there is one more affordable to memory and style I'd like to learn